# Firebase with index merging + orderby doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to make a request with a property filtered.
I know with firebase , we can't use the where condition with multiple differents fields Or use Where with a field property A and order by property B.  So i test with the Index.

I create an index for a collection

**DB**

collection : geo

Example of data :

```
{
date: 1638926138,
localisation: { latitude: 48.120599, longitude: 2.0256055 },
po: 1251653A,
st: pQN8,
user: OeS2
}
```

I create an index:

```
Id collection: geo
fields index : date => descending, localisation.latitude => ascending
status : activate
```

Request:

```
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore";
firestore()
  .collection(COLLECTION)
   .where("localisation.latitude", ">=", lat_min)
   .where("localisation.latitude", "<=", lat_max)
   .get()
   .then(querySnapshot => {})
```

It's work ok ( but i would like to use my index with the field 'date')

```
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore";
firestore()
  .collection(COLLECTION)
   .where("localisation.latitude", ">=", lat_min)
   .where("localisation.latitude", "<=", lat_max)
   .orderBy('date')
   .get()
   .then(querySnapshot => {})
```

**Error**

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>
> Error: firebase.firestore().collection().orderBy() Invalid query. Initial Query.orderBy() parameter: date has to be the same as the Query.where() fieldPath parameter(s): localisation.latitude when an inequality operator is invoked

Thanks for help!

**Resolve**

oh it's work thanks
just for now
if i would test with this  request

```
firestore()
                .collection(COLLECTION)
                .orderBy("localisation.latitude")
                .where("localisation.latitude", ">=", lat_min)
                .where("localisation.latitude", "<=", lat_max)
                .orderBy('date', 'desc')
                .get()
```

width the index :

```
localisation.latitude => ascending
date => descending
```

But I test with localisation.longitude

**Other Test**

My index :

```
  localisation.latitude => ascending
  localisation.longitude => ascending
  date => descending
```

my request

```
 firestore()
                .collection(COLLECTION)
                .orderBy("localisation.latitude")
                .where("localisation.latitude", ">=", lat_min)
                .where("localisation.latitude", "<=", lat_max)
                .orderBy("localisation.longitude")
                .where("localisation.longitude", ">=", lon_min)
                .where("localisation.longitude", "<=", lon_max)
                .orderBy('date', 'desc')
```

It's not work

**Error**

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: firebase.firestore().collection().where() Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, != or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'localisation.latitude' and 'localisation.longitude'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you'll need to order on `localisation.latitude` first, and only then on `date`.

```
firestore()
  .collection(COLLECTION)
   .orderBy("localisation.latitude")
   .where("localisation.latitude", ">=", lat_min)
   .where("localisation.latitude", "<=", lat_max)
   .orderBy('date')
```

You may need to create an index for this specific order too.

Having these two `orderBy` calls in the query also means that your results will be in `localisation.latitude` order first, and in `date` order second. There is no way to change this:

If you want the results in date order first, you will need to reorder them in your application code.

---

Unrelated: given that you're filtering by latitude, I recommend checking out the documentation on [geoqueries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries), which allow you to search for documents in an area.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's works,  I updated my post for a another test with 3 fields ,  localisation.latitude + localisation.longitude + date , with the good order and the request doesn't work ... , i don't understand.

Comment: thanks i will open a new post. Thanks