# Firebase with index merging ( multiple properties )+ orderby doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I create an index for a collection

**DB**

collection : collection1
Example of data :

```
   {
    date: 1638926138,
    azd: { la: 481.120599, lo: 221.0256055 },
    po: 123456,
    st: 123456,
    user: OeS2,
    }
```

**INDEX 1**

Id collection: collection1
fields index : azd.la -> ascending, date => descending,
status : activate

**Request 1**

I start with this requets , it's work

```
firestore()
                .collection(COLLECTION)
                .orderBy("azd.la")
                .where("azd.la", ">=", a_min)
                .where("azd.la", "<=", a_max)
                .orderBy('date', 'desc')
                .get()
```

**If i Update my index with 3 properties ( azd.la, azd.lo, date)**

**INDEX 1 updated**

Id collection: collection1
fields index : azd.la -> ascending, azd.lo -> ascending, date => descending,
status : activate

```
 firestore()
                    .collection(COLLECTION)
                    .orderBy("azd.la")
                    .where("azd.la", ">=", a_min)
                    .where("azd.la", "<=", a_max)
                    .orderby("azd.lo")
                    .where("azd.lo", ">=", b_min)
                     .where("azd.lo", "<=", b_max)
                    .orderBy('date', 'desc')
                    .get()
```

I have an error
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: firebase.firestore().collection().where() Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, != or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'azd.la' and 'azd.lo'

**I Have an other index but I don't know if the problem is exacly the same thing**

**INDEX 2**

Id collection: collection1
fields index : azd.la -> ascending, azd.lo -> ascending, po -> ascending, date => descending,
status : activate

```
 firestore()
                        .collection(COLLECTION)
                        .orderBy("azd.la")
                        .where("azd.la", ">=", a_min)
                        .where("azd.la", "<=", a_max)
                        .orderby("azd.lo")
                        .where("azd.lo", ">=", b_min)
                        .where("azd.lo", "<=", b_max)
                        .orderby("po")
                        .where("po", "==", 123456)
                        .orderBy('date', 'desc')
                        .get()
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work:

```
.collection(COLLECTION)
.orderBy("azd.la")
.where("azd.la", ">=", a_min)
.where("azd.la", "<=", a_max)
.orderby("azd.lo")
.where("azd.lo", ">=", b_min)
.where("azd.lo", "<=", b_max)
```

From the documentation on [query limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

So there is no way to perform a range query on two fields, like your longitude and latitude here.

This is also why in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70343019/209103) I recommended checking out the Firebase documentation on [implementing geoqueries on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries). If you want to know more about this limit on Firestore, and how the geoqueries solution works around that, have a look at this video of a talk I did a few years ago: [Querying Firebase and Firestore based on geographic location or distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q)

Comment: thanks for the geolocalisation but , it's an example of data. 
It's not possible to have more 2 properties for a condition where ? 
if i use an index with po, st and date.  I have an error too.

If i understand, I can't use 2 properties with the condition where ?

Comment: You can have equality checks on many properties, but all range queries and `not` conditions must be on the same field. I recommend checking out the video I linked to understand why that is.